# how can I sort a text file in php

Tags: php

```
english, lang1, lang2
rat, rat_lang1, rat_lang2
ball, ball_lang1, ball_lang2
air, air_lang1, air_lang2
```

If I have this text file I read in php, how can I sort it starting the second line, the first line being the heading of the file. So that the file will print out like..

```
english....
air....
ball...
rat....
```

I read the file using `fopen`, put it in `$content` using `fread`, used `explode` with new line. I can see the array of lines but cannot figure out how to sort it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The file is multi line with a break after lang2.

Comment: funny enough, the function called [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) is what you need

Comment: Instead of `fread()` and `explode()`, you can use `file()` to read a file into an array of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of this solution was answered within the comments in response to your question. All put together you're looking for something like:

```
<?php
$f = file("text.txt"); //read the text file into an array
$newf = fopen("newtext.txt", "w+"); //open another file
$header = $f[0]; //store the first element of the array as $header
echo $header."<br>"; //and echo the header
fwrite($newf, $header); //write the header to the new file
array_shift($f); //then remove the first element of the array i.e. the header
sort($f); //sort the array (no flag param = alphabetical sort)
foreach($f as $line){ //loop through the sorted array
    echo $line."<br>"; //print each element as it's own line
    fwrite($newf, trim($line)."\n"); //write other elements to new file on own line
}
fclose($newf); //close the file
?>
```

Comment: I ran into some spacing issues but seems to work great. How do I get it to save it in a new file? I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$header' (T_VARIABLE)" when I tried implementing the changes to the script.

Comment: Ensure you ended all lines with a semi colon (;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = trim(file_get_contents('sort_test.txt'));
$data = explode("\n", $data);
$array_order = array();
$fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
$file = fopen($fileLocation, "w");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
   ($i > 0) ? $array_order[$i] = $data[$i] : fwrite($file, $data[0]); 
}
sort($array_order);
$data = implode("\n", $array_order);
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
echo 'file created - location::' . $fileLocation;
```

Output myfile.txt

```
english, lang1, lang2
air, air_lang1, air_lang2
ball, ball_lang1, ball_lang2
rat, rat_lang1, rat_lang2
```

Maybe the new file (myfile.txt) will needs write permission to the directory you are writing to , in my case the file has been stored into C:/.../htdocs/myfile.txt